# Моментальный обмен сообщений в web

Tags: веб-программирование

Какие технологии существует для реализации моментального обмена сообщений через веб? Я слышал только про comet, может, кто знает про другие.

Comment: Чем тебе не нравится COMET? 

Comment: да нравится мне он просто хотел узнать другие способы

Answer (score 3):

Если я правильно понял, то вам следует посмотреть в сторону [WebSocket](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) и обзор это технологии [здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/webdev/79038/)

А на чем вы будете писать серверную часть - ваше личное дело.

Comment: А чем Ajax плох?

Comment: Ну Ajax это не совсем то что мне надо и отправлять каждую секунду запрос я думаю что это не совсем хороший способ